# How to get callback for every played second in android media player

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am using android media player to play a video in my application . I want show a button to skip the video after 5 seconds of the actual play. Initially i show "Skip Video in 5s". Then ,as the player keeps on playing the video , it will keep on updating the button text with " Skip video in 4s" and so on , every second. At last it will show "Skip Video".

I do not know how to get callback for every second played . Because i do not update the button text , when player is buffering or player is paused .

So far i have tried :

```
public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    updateSkipButtonUI();

}
```

But as i tested on some devices onBufferingUpdate method gets called every second when the player is playing the video.
But on some devices it does not gets called once the buffering percentage reaches 100%.

I also tried

```
mMediaPlayer.setOnInfoListener(this);
    @Override
public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(what == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_START)
    {
        //Player started buffering. Player internally pauses . 
        stopTimerToUpdateSkipButton();
    }
    else if(what == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_END)
    {
        // Buffering has ended . Content is ready to play.
        startTimerToUpdateSkipButton();
    }

    return what == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_START || what == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_END;
}
```

But OnInfo method also gets called sometimes . Sometimes it does not gets called.

I do not know what else to try . Please help.